# How to center a text using printf with `^` flag in Java?

Tags: java, string, formatting, printf, flags

I know I can do it as follows:

```
String s = "Hello";
int maxLength = 10;
System.out.print(getSpaces((maxLength - s.length()) / 2) + s + getSpaces((maxLength - s.length()) / 2));
```

But I need to do it in a simple way. According to this page: [Printf for Java Specification 3.0](http://sharkysoft.com/software/java/lava3/printf/javadocs/com/sharkysoft/printf/doc-files/specification.htm) (Section 9. flags):

I can center the text using `^` as a flag with `printf()` like this:

```
String s = "Hello";
int maxLength = 10;
System.out.printf("%^" + maxLength + "s", s);
```

But I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '^'
```

What is the correct way to use `^` flag with `printf()`?

Comment: That documentation link you posted isn't for standard Java, it appears to be for a "Lava3 Printf" library that you can install. The link for it is here: http://sharkysoft.com/software/java/lava3/printf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format String syntax, including information on specifiers and flags can be found here: [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

I don't see use of `^` as a flag anywhere in this documentation.

I believe that your specification in the link above isn't for standard Java but rather for a 3rd party library called Lava3 Printf produced by [SharkySoft](http://sharkysoft.com/software/). Please let us know if this is the library you are using, or if you're trying to do this coding with core Java.

Comment: Seems it's a 3rd party library :(