# COMP SCI 101 - Centering Fields Using Printf

Tags: java, netbeans, printf

I am creating a Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion table using the printf function.

In my notes, I see that I should be able to center the output using the ^ flag immediately after the % for printf.  However, Netbeans always gives me an error message when I run the program.

I was wondering if anybody can help me center my output.  My code is as follows.

I have looked through questions that have already been answered. However, they do not correspond with what I was taught in class thus far and as such - I cannot use it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class CelsToFahrTable {

/**
 * Main argument prints a Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion table
 * using integer Celsius degrees from 0 to 40
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // declare variables
    double Cels; //control variable (Celsius Temperature)

    System.out.printf("%10s\t%10s%n", "Celsius", "Fahrenheit"); 
    //prints headers Celsius and Fahrenheit at the top to signify what the data
    //below means. Celsius should take up 10 columns then tab to Fahrenheit
    //which again takes up 10 columns

    for ( Cels = 0; Cels <= 40; Cels++)
        //creates count-controlled loop using for statement
        //Cels initialized to 0, continues expression until 40 and increments
        //by 1 degree each time

        System.out.printf("%10.0f%10.1f%n", Cels, 1.8*Cels+32.0);
    //creates table showing Celsius temperature followed by its corresponding
    //Fahrenheit temperature. Celsius temp is 10 columns with no decimals.  
    //Fahrenheit temp is 10 columns with a 1 decimal precision.

    //Note: I tried to center each field using "^" but it gave me an error 
    //every time

}//end main
```

The "^" would be placed in the final:

```
System.out.printf ("%^10.0f%^10.1f%n", Cels, 1.8*Cels+32.0"
```

----However when I type that code I get an error in Netbeans.

Comment: Where is it you are trying to put the `^`?

Comment: I believe ^ is a bitwise operator. Not power of.

Comment: The "^" would be placed in the final: System.out.printf ("%^10.0f%^10.1f%n", Cels, 1.8*Cels+32.0"   ----However when I type that code I get an error in Netbeans.

Comment: Don't blindly follow your notes. Go read the `printf` format rules in the [`Formatter` class javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: I did and it does not list any ways to center these fields @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Center them on what? The `System.out` is standard output, usually the console. How can Java know its display size?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I want to center them underneath their headers.  In this example, they would be center under "Celsius" and "Fahrenheit"

Comment: [^ is not a valid printf flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468467/how-to-center-a-text-using-printf-with-flag-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look through the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) javadoc, Java does not have a flag to center the output of printf, and there is no `^` flag.

Your notes are probably referring to the [Lava library](http://www.sharkysoft.com/archive/lava/overview/), which comes with "an advanced" Java port of the C printf function. As specified in the Lava [specification](http://www.sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm) under the section on flags, `^` is the flag for centering output.

As specified elsewhere on SO, you can use the [StringUtils.center](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#center%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method from the [Apache Commons Lang Library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi), or devise [a method of your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8155547/336656).

Comment: Thank you very much for your information.  Through this post, I learned that ^ is not a valid flag.  Since, my professor has not taught us how to use the StringUtils.center method, I won't use it.  But I did tinker around with the column width in the final printf I used in my code to make it appear centered.  And it looks pretty good.